# Modify woocommerce checkout error message from stripe using fiter or hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
function my_woocommerce_add_error( $error ) {
    if($error ) {
        $error+= 'Please chat with us for help';
    }
    return $error;
}
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_get_error_messages', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```

I am looking to append something to the existing error message.

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woo-stripe-payment/tags/3.3.39/includes/wc-stripe-functions.php#L1091

How to use the filter 'wc_stripe_get_error_messages' to modify the checkout error messages.

How can i use this filter to alter the messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using a concatenation assignment.

```
function my_woocommerce_add_error( $error ) {

if ( $error ) {

    $add = 'Please chat with us for help';

    $error .= $error . $add;
}
return $error;
}
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_get_error_messages', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```